# ConstraintLayout: How to center a text between two buttons of varying sizes

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I'm making a dialog with a header that contains a "Cancel" button, a title and finally a "Save" button. See image. The title is constrained between the buttons. However, when one of the buttons are longer than the other the title moves to one side as it is told to stay in the middle between the buttons.

How can I make the title view be centered below the drag handle and at the same time let it expand all the way to the buttons without overlapping them?

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: the title will expand or button will expand?

Comment: The title should expand up until the buttons

Comment: see my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so inspired by some of your answers I started looking at guidelines. The idea was to use two guidelines, one on each side of the view, and set the distance from the parent to the guideline as the width of the biggest button plus any margin. Final code looks like this:

```
    val biggestWidth = if (cancelButton.width > saveButton.width) {
       cancelButton.width + cancelButton.marginStart
    } else {
        saveButton.width + saveButton.marginEnd
    }
    guidelineRight.setGuidelineEnd(biggestWidth)
    guidelineLeft.setGuidelineBegin(biggestWidth)
```

The title is centered between the two guidelines.

[image: Result]

Note that this width calculation must happen after the view has been laid out. Use `view.doOnLayout { }` and call your calculation from there.

Answer (score 0):

this is the only hack where you can set title without overlapping in centre of the screen

make one temp button same as long button in invisible mode

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="long cancel"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="long cancel"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="save"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="@dimen/_10sdp"
        android:text="title"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/btn1"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/btn3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**EDIT**

this is another way, but this will be a mess when you have a very large title

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="long cancel"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/txt"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="save"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/txt"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="@dimen/_10sdp"
        android:text="title dfgfd gdg dfgdfg dfgdfg  fdgfdfgd fgddf dfgdgdfgdfg dfg dfgfdg df"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Edit**

if you know max length of `long cancel` button you can set `app:layout_constraintWidth_percent` to `TextView` based on that button width

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/black"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="@dimen/_10sdp"
    android:text="title dfgfd gdg dfgdfg dfgdfg  fdgfdfgd fgddf dfgdgdfgdfg dfg dfgfdg df"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/guideline"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/guideline"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.4" />
```

Comment: It seems a bit overkill to create two hidden buttons and add logic to find out which of them should be largest and set the size accordingly.. Is this the only way?

Comment: I see.. I'm thinking about a combination of your approach and GraphicStone's answer; creating a hidden drag handle which is constrained in the same way as with your two hidden buttons. Will try and come back to you.

Answer (score 0):

[image]I just implement the same functionality on three buttons that align horizontal and don't overlap each other. 
Please create views in the same way below implementation.

```
<Button
                android:id="@+id/btnExit"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/dp_1"
                android:background="@drawable/bluebtn_gradient_rectangle"
                android:text="@string/exit"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/btnMemoryPreview"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvFill" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnMemoryPreview"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/dp_1"
                android:background="@drawable/bluebtn_gradient_rectangle"
                android:text="@string/user_memory_preview"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/UserMemoryWrite"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/btnExit"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvFill" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/UserMemoryWrite"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/dp_1"
                android:background="@drawable/bluebtn_gradient_rectangle"
                android:text="@string/rfid_write"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/btnMemoryPreview"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvFill" />
```

Answer (score -1):

Your drag handle seems to be at the center of the layout. So you can relate the title to left and right of the parent instead buttons. But still overlapping could be possible if title and cancel button text is lengthy.

Comment: As you say yourself, overlapping will still happen :/

Answer (score -1):

You can center the title with respect to the drag handle but then cannot expand the TextView between cancel and save button. I think both cannot be done simultaneoulsy.

You can use the below code to center the title w.r.t the  drag handle

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/dp_80"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/dp_8"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp_8"
        android:background="@color/divider"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp_8"
        android:text="title"
        android:textSize="@dimen/sp_24"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/view"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/view"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/view" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/cancel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="cancel"
        android:textSize="@dimen/sp_16"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/title"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/view" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/save"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="save"
        android:textSize="@dimen/sp_16"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/title"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/view" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image: This would be the final result]

Answer (score -2):

[image]

[image: Set constraints to left of layout and right of layout]

[image]

Remove Constrainsts button to textView and set TextView Constraints to left and right of layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="ButtonButtonButtonButtonButtonButtonButtonButton"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="wTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextVwTextViewTextView
        TextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextVwTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextView
        TextVwTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextVTextViewTextViewTextViewTextView
        TextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextView
        TextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextView"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Without fixed button size

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="ButtonButtonButtonButtonButtonButtonButtonButton"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="wTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextVwTextViewTextView
        TextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextVwTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextView
        TextVwTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextVTextViewTextViewTextViewTextView
        TextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextView
        TextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextView"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button2"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Button"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: How would this overcome the problem op mentioned regarding title "let it expand all the way to the buttons without overlapping them"

Comment: In above image title will not overlap and button will adjust

Comment: Please update image with a long title and one button with long text to show us what you mean.

Comment: Interesting! And could this be done without fixed size on the buttons?

Comment: Yes. It could be done with fixed size. Check updated image and code block

Comment: Yeah, now the elements has `layout_weight` set instead, which in practice is fixed width. In my case the buttons should determine its own size at runtime, not according to any predefined weights. I found a solution using guidelines. Posted it further up here. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score -2):

**TextView**

```
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
```

**Cancel button**

```
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/your_text_view_id"
```

**Save button**

```
app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/your_text_view_id"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
```

That way your buttons can expand freely without overlapping the text at the centre.

Comment: I don't see how this will work. Yes, the title will be centered in the parent, but the buttons will be halfway out of the screen and the title will overlap the buttons if long. :/

Comment: Place a vertical `Guideline` to the start of your `TextView` and another to the end. Then constrain your views to the guidelines